# Filtered last transaction

Tags: sql, oracle

first: I have two tables with a primary key((Agent_ID). I want to join both tables, filter Agent_Type =1 and status =1

Second: get the last active year total transaction value monthly wise who is not done any transaction for the last three months.

Agent table

```
Agent_ID     Agent_Type
234           1
456           1
567           1
678           0
```

Agent_Transaction table

```
Agent_ID     Amount   Transaction_Date  status
234           70          23/7/2019      1
234           54          11/6/2019      0
234           30          23/5/2019      1
456           56          12/1/2019      1
456           80          15/3/2019      1
456           99          20/2/2019      1
456           76          23/12/2018     1
567           56          10/10/2018     0
567           60          30/6/2018      1
456
```

```sql
select  Agent_ID,CONCAT(Extract(MONTH from Agent_Transaction.Transaction_Date),
       EXTRACT (YEAR FROM Agent_Transaction.Transaction_Date))as MONTH_YEAR,
       SUM(Agent_Transaction.Amount)AS TOTAL
from Agent
inner join Agent_Transaction
      on Agent_Transaction.Agent_ID = Agent.Agent_ID
where Agent.Agent_Type='1' AND Agent_Transaction.status='1'  AND  
      (Agent_Transaction.Transaction_Date between ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-3) and SYSDATE)
 GROUP BY Agent.Agent_ID, 
       CONCAT(Extract(MONTH from Agent_Transaction.Transaction_Date),EXTRACT (YEAR FROM Agent_Transaction.Transaction_Date)),
       Agent_Transaction.Amount
```

But I didn't get what I expected.

Comment: Can you please share the expected output so that it will become crystal clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood the requirement, you can use the following query:

```
SELECT
    A.AGENT_ID,
    TO_CHAR(TRUNC(ATR.TRANSACTION_DATE, 'MONTH'), 'MONYYYY'), --  YOU CAN USE DIFFERENT FORMAT ACCORDING TO REQUIREMENT
    SUM(AMOUNT) AS TOTAL_MONTHWISE_AMOUNT -- MONTHWISE TRANSACTION TOTAL
FROM
    AGENT A
    JOIN AGENT_TRANSACTION ATR ON ( A.AGENT_ID = ATR.AGENT_ID )
WHERE
    -- EXCLUDING THE AGENTS WHICH HAVE DONE NO TRANSACTION IN LAST THREE MONTHS USING FOLLOWING NOT IN
    ATR.AGENT_ID NOT IN (
        SELECT
            DISTINCT ATR_IN1.AGENT_ID
        FROM
            AGENT_TRANSACTION ATR_IN1
        WHERE
            ATR_IN1.TRANSACTION_DATE > ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, - 3)
            AND ATR_IN1.STATUS = 1 -- YOU CAN USE IT ACCORDING TO REQUIREMENT
    )
    -- FETCHING LAST YEAR DATA
    AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ATR.TRANSACTION_DATE) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, - 12)) 
    AND A.AGENT_TYPE = 1
    AND ATR.STATUS = 1
GROUP BY
    A.AGENT_ID,
    TRUNC(ATR.TRANSACTION_DATE, 'MONTH');
```

Please comment if minor changes are required or you need different logic.

Cheers!!

**-- Update --**

Updated the query after OP described the original issue:

```
SELECT
    AGENT_ID,
    TO_CHAR(TRUNC(TRANSACTION_DATE, 'MONTH'), 'MONYYYY'), --  YOU CAN USE DIFFERENT FORMAT ACCORDING TO REQUIREMENT
    SUM(AMOUNT) AS TOTAL_MONTHWISE_AMOUNT -- MONTHWISE TRANSACTION TOTAL
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            A.AGENT_ID,
            TRUNC(ATR.TRANSACTION_DATE, 'MONTH') AS TRANSACTION_DATE,
            MAX(TRUNC(ATR.TRANSACTION_DATE, 'MONTH')) OVER(
                PARTITION BY A.AGENT_ID
            ) AS LAST_TR_DATE,
            AMOUNT,
            AGENT_TYPE,
            STATUS
        FROM
            AGENT A
            JOIN AGENT_TRANSACTION ATR ON ( A.AGENT_ID = ATR.AGENT_ID )
        WHERE
            A.AGENT_TYPE = 1
            AND ATR.STATUS = 1
    )
WHERE
    -- EXCLUDING THE AGENTS WHICH HAVE DONE NO TRANSACTION IN LAST THREE MONTHS USING FOLLOWING NOT IN
    LAST_TR_DATE > ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, - 3) 
    -- FETCHING LAST YEAR DATA
    AND TRANSACTION_DATE BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(LAST_TR_DATE, - 12) AND LAST_TR_DATE
GROUP BY
    AGENT_ID,
    TRANSACTION_DATE;
```

Cheers!!

**-- Update --**

Your exact query should look like this:

```
SELECT
    AGENT_ID,
    TO_CHAR(TRUNC(TX_TIME, 'MONTH'), 'MONYYYY') AS MONTHYEAR,
    SUM(TX_VALUE) AS TOTALMONTHWISE
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            A.AGENT_ID,
            TRUNC(ATR.TX_TIME, 'MONTH') AS TX_TIME, -- changed this alias name
            MAX(TRUNC(ATR.TX_TIME, 'MONTH')) OVER(
                PARTITION BY A.AGENT_ID
            ) AS LAST_TR_DATE,
            ATR.TX_VALUE,
            A.AGENT_TYPE_ID
        FROM
            TBLEZ_AGENT A
            JOIN TBLEZ_TRANSACTION ATR ON ( A.AGENT_ID = ATR.SRC_AGENT_ID )
        WHERE
            A.AGENT_TYPE_ID = '3'
            AND ATR.STATUS = '0'
            AND ATR.TX_TYPE_ID = '5'
    )
WHERE
    LAST_TR_DATE < ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, - 3)
    AND ( TX_TIME BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(LAST_TR_DATE, - 12) AND LAST_TR_DATE )
GROUP BY
    AGENT_ID,
    TX_TIME;
```

**-- UPDATE --**

In response to this comment -- **Hi Tejash, How to get the total day-wise to above my scenario? **

```
SELECT
    AGENT_ID,
    TX_TIME,
    SUM(TX_VALUE) AS TOTALDAYWISE
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            A.AGENT_ID,
            TRUNC(ATR.TX_TIME) AS TX_TIME, -- changed TRUNC INPUT PARAMETER -- REMOVED MONTH IN TRUNC
            MAX(TRUNC(ATR.TX_TIME)) OVER( -- changed TRUNC INPUT PARAMETER -- REMOVED MONTH IN TRUNC
                PARTITION BY A.AGENT_ID
            ) AS LAST_TR_DATE, 
            ATR.TX_VALUE,
            A.AGENT_TYPE_ID
        FROM
            TBLEZ_AGENT A
            JOIN TBLEZ_TRANSACTION ATR ON ( A.AGENT_ID = ATR.SRC_AGENT_ID )
        WHERE
            A.AGENT_TYPE_ID = '3'
            AND ATR.STATUS = '0'
            AND ATR.TX_TYPE_ID = '5'
    )
WHERE
    LAST_TR_DATE < ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, - 3)
    AND ( TRUNC(TX_TIME, 'MONTH') BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(LAST_TR_DATE, - 12) AND LAST_TR_DATE ) 
-- changed TRUNC INPUT PARAMETER -- ADDED MONTH IN TRUNC
GROUP BY
    AGENT_ID,
    TX_TIME;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Second: get the last active year total transaction value monthly wise who is not done any transaction for the last three months. -- This was the requirement. Can you please specify what you are expecting?

Comment: Hi thank you Tejash but only filtering last year transaction and give subtotal for that monthly wise. but I am not expecting like that. Example:   one agent did transactions from Jan 2017 to May 2019, he didn't do any transaction last three months(jun2019 -Aug2019). so then I want to get their transaction from May 2018 to May 2019 transactions total monthly wise.

Comment: Can you please edit the question and add the exact query that you are running.

Comment: pls check my exact query

Comment: I uploaded an extract query but
 I am getting this error msg "ATR"."TX_TIME": invalid identifier

Comment: Actually you have given alias name to date. I have changed it in my latest updated answer. Use that query now.

Comment: Tejash, now the query is working but it is filtering who are done the transaction on Aug 2019, July 2019 and Jun 2019. I need to filter who is not do any transaction last three months from system date

Comment: Yes, need to use < in last where condition .. updated thequery.check

Comment: Thank you so much, Tejash for your support. it is working.

Comment: Hi Tejash, How to get the total day-wise to above my scenario?

Comment: Hi Bro, Pls support me this scenario as well,

Comment: Tejash, plz help me if get daily bases subtotal not monthly wise

Comment: Can you please create a new question with fresh requirement, so that it does not create mess.

Comment: sure, check this link I was created the new fresh question 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57798212/filter-transaction-daily-wise

Comment: Bro, i attached my fresh question stakoverflow link. could u plz help?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    A.AGENT_ID,
    TO_CHAR(TRUNC(ATR.TX_TIME, 'MONTH'), 'MONYYYY') AS MONTHYEAR,
    SUM(ATR.TX_VALUE) AS TOTALMONTHWISE
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            A.AGENT_ID,
            TRUNC(ATR.TX_TIME, 'MONTH') AS TRANSC_DATE,
            MAX(TRUNC(ATR.TX_TIME, 'MONTH')) OVER(
                PARTITION BY A.AGENT_ID
            ) AS LAST_TR_DATE,
            ATR.TX_VALUE,
            A.AGENT_TYPE_ID
        FROM
            TBLEZ_AGENT A
            JOIN TBLEZ_TRANSACTION ATR ON ( A.AGENT_ID = ATR.SRC_AGENT_ID )
        WHERE
            A.AGENT_TYPE_ID = '3'
            AND ATR.STATUS = '0'
            AND ATR.TX_TYPE_ID = '5'
    )
WHERE
    LAST_TR_DATE > ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, - 3)
    AND ( TX_TIME BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(LAST_TR_DATE, - 12) AND LAST_TR_DATE )
GROUP BY
    A.AGENT_ID,TRUNC(ATR.TX_TIME, 'MONTH')
```

Comment: This is not the query that I have suggested . You need to remove alias names from outer `SELECT` and `WHERE`

Comment: I tried you last update query still i am getting  "ORA-00904: "TX_TIME": invalid identifier" this error msg bro

Comment: hi Tejash, I tried ur lastest updated quey also still i am getting "ORA-00904: "TX_TIME": invalid identifier" error msg. Appreciate if you could check my query above. help me..