# Filter Transaction Daily wise

Tags: sql

1. I have two tables with a primary key(`Agent_ID`). I want to join both tables, filter `Agent_Type =3` and `status =0` and `Transaction=5`
2. Get the last active year total transaction value daily wise who is not done any transaction for the last three months.

I was tried code in below but I couldn't get a correct answer

```
SELECT
AGENT_ID,
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TX_TIME,'DD-MON-YYYY')) AS DAYMONTHYEAR,
SUM(TX_VALUE) AS TOTALDAILYWISE,
count(*)as Transaction_count
FROM
(
    SELECT
        A.AGENT_ID,
        TO_DATE(ATR.TX_TIME,'DD-MON-YYYY') AS TX_TIME,
        MAX(TO_DATE(ATR.TX_TIME,'DD-MON-YYYY')) OVER(
            PARTITION BY A.AGENT_ID
        ) AS LAST_TR_DATE,
        ATR.TX_VALUE,
        A.AGENT_TYPE_ID
    FROM
        TBLEZ_AGENT A
        JOIN TBLEZ_TRANSACTION ATR ON ( A.AGENT_ID = ATR.SRC_AGENT_ID )
    WHERE
        A.AGENT_TYPE_ID = '3'
        AND ATR.STATUS = '0'
        AND ATR.TX_TYPE_ID = '5'
)
WHERE
LAST_TR_DATE < (SYSDATE - 90)
AND ( TX_TIME BETWEEN(LAST_TR_DATE - 365) AND LAST_TR_DATE )
GROUP BY
AGENT_ID,
TX_TIME;
```

pls support how to get transaction daily wise

Comment: Your inner query looks OK based on what you specified.  A small suggestion here, though -- when you filter or join on NUMERIC fields, you should not include quotation marks `(')`.  It should just be `AND ATR.TX_TYPE_ID = 5`.

Does `last active year total transaction value daily wise` mean you want to get the total transaction value for the last active year?  What do you mean by `daily wise`?  Please post a sample output of what you're looking for.

Comment: Unrelated, but: why are you storing date values in a `varchar` column - that is a really bad design decision

Comment: Yes, Daily wise last active transaction Example: one Agent did not do any transaction last three months from today(5th June 19 - 5th Sep19). I want to get their transaction 5th May 19 to 4th Jun 19(one year transaction).

Comment: What is the issue in this query? you are not getting the correct answer? what you are getting then? also `5th May 19 to 4th Jun 19` is 13 months - 1 day. it is not one year.

Comment: Tejash, I am not getting the correct answer, I am getting who are done the transaction on Aug 2019 also. but I want last one-year(365Day) transaction daily wise subtotal  who are not done any transaction last three months(90days)

Comment: I guess you need to change `TX_TIME BETWEEN(LAST_TR_DATE - 365) AND LAST_TR_DATE` to `TX_TIME BETWEEN(SYSDATE - 365) AND SYSDATE` for looking only last 1 year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT
    AGENT_ID,
    TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TX_TIME, 'DD-MON-YYYY')) AS DAYMONTHYEAR,
    SUM(TX_VALUE) AS TOTALMONTHWISE,
    COUNT(*) AS TRANSACTION_COUNT
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            A.AGENT_ID,
            TO_DATE(ATR.TX_TIME, 'DD-MON-YYYY') AS TX_TIME,
            MAX(TO_DATE(ATR.TX_TIME, 'DD-MON-YYYY')) OVER(
                PARTITION BY A.AGENT_ID
            ) AS LAST_TR_DATE,
            ATR.TX_VALUE,
            A.AGENT_TYPE_ID
        FROM
            TBLEZ_AGENT A
            JOIN TBLEZ_TRANSACTION ATR ON ( A.AGENT_ID = ATR.SRC_AGENT_ID )
        WHERE
            A.AGENT_TYPE_ID = '3'
            AND ATR.STATUS = '0'
            AND ATR.TX_TYPE_ID = '5'
    )
WHERE
    LAST_TR_DATE < TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS( SYSDATE, - 3 ))
    AND  TX_TIME BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(LAST_TR_DATE, -13) AND LAST_TR_DATE - 1 
GROUP BY
    AGENT_ID,
    TX_TIME;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: it is filtering who is done on Aug2019 also, but I want to filter  who is not done any transaction last three months